# mousedown.konva event listener unhooked after setting shape.draggable(false)

Tags: konvajs

*This is a self-answer question partly for my future self when I've forgotten about this quirk, and hopefully it will save others the sideshow of finding the solution for themselves.*

So I'm coding up a customer shape. I wanted to listen to mouse & touch events on the shape so I used the events with a .konva suffix, example mousedown.konva. These events are set up by Konva itself so all I need to do is add my own listener. This works for standard shapes like Rect and Circle too.

However, I observed a 'bug' whereby after setting myShape.draggable(false), the mousedown.konva listener stopped being fired.

It looks like this

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      }), 

      layer = new Konva.Layer(),
 
      rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 400,
        y: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        stroke: 'magenta',  
        fill: 'magenta',  
        draggable: true
      }),   
        
      rect3 = rect2.clone({x: 510, fill: 'cyan', stroke: 'cyan'});
  
layer.add(rect2, rect3);
stage.add(layer);
 
 
rect2.on('mousedown.konva', function(evt){
  console.log('rect2.mousedown');
})
rect2.on('mousemove.konva', function(evt){
  console.log('rect2.mousemove');
})
rect2.on('mouseup.konva', function(evt){
  console.log('rect2.mouseup');
})
rect2.on('click.konva', function(evt){
  console.log('rect2.click');
})
rect2.on('dragstart.konva', function(evt){
  console.log('rect2.dragstart');
})

rect3.on('click', function(){
  stage.draggable(false);
  layer.draggable(false)  
  rect2.draggable(false);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>Mouseover, click & drag the pink rect and watch the console. Pay attention to mousedown messages. Now click the blue rect (sets pinkrect.draggable(false). Now try mousedown on the pink rect again - tis gone!!</p>
 
 
<div id="container" class='container'>
```

What gives ?

Answer (score 0):

So - if you look at the code for konva/node.ts you will see the following, which is triggered when you change the draggable attr on a shape.

```js
  _dragChange() {
    if (this.attrs.draggable) {
      this._listenDrag();
    } else {
      // remove event listeners
      this._dragCleanup();

      /*
       * force drag and drop to end
       * if this node is currently in
       * drag and drop mode
       */
      var stage = this.getStage();
      if (!stage) {
        return;
      }
      const dragElement = DD._dragElements.get(this._id);
      const isDragging = dragElement && dragElement.dragStatus === 'dragging';
      const isReady = dragElement && dragElement.dragStatus === 'ready';

      if (isDragging) {
        this.stopDrag();
      } else if (isReady) {
        DD._dragElements.delete(this._id);
      }
    }
  }

  _dragCleanup() {
    this.off('mousedown.konva');
    this.off('touchstart.konva');
  }
```

The critical point for use is line 6 where function this._dragCleanup() is called. In that func, which you can see toward the end of the code, the mousedown.konva listener is removed.   Note that the developer has retricted the 'off' so it it affects only the konva listeners. Nice.

Conclusion - don't rely on  events provided by the lib authors - unless stated as guaranteed it would be pragmatic to distrust them.